# Why ExternalContextCreator is not exported from @nestjs/core?

Tags: nestjs

Why `ExternalContextCreator` global provider is not exported from @nestjs/core?

In NestJS source code, the `create` static method of `InternalCoreModuleFactory` registers `ExternalContextCreator` as global provider.

But it is not exported from "packages/core/helpers/index.ts"

As a result, in case I want to import this provider into my project, I need to import it like this:

```
import { ExternalContextCreator } from '@nestjs/core/helpers/external-context-creator';`
```

Instead of this:

```
import { ExternalContextCreator } from '@nestjs/core';
```

So, my question is why

```
ExternalContextCreator
```

not exported from

```
"packages/core/helpers/index.ts"?
```

Comment: AFAIK `ExternalContextCreator` is an internal provider (I don't know what it does nor why it was made), so it shouldn't be exported from `@nestjs/core`. I didn't get why do you need that provider

Comment: @MicaelLevi Thank you for you comment. Actually I don't need it in my projects. I am just learning NestJS under the hood and found it is registered as global provider but not exported from the core folder. So that's why I raised this question.

Comment: got you. Looks like that that provider was made for usage at `@nestjs/graphql`, as you can see [here](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Anestjs%20ExternalContextCreator&type=code). Since it's a package under `@nestjs` scope, I'd say that it is still internal.